# HighChart with more than 50 data points breaks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to create a bubble chart using the JS HighChart in Angular2+.  Whenever there are more than 50 data points (bubbles), the graph breaks.  There are the correct number of bubbles in the correct positions (x,y plots) with all different colors but the sizes are all the same even though the z-values are all different.  (I am outputing the z-values in a tooltip and the z-values are accurate)
This function is how I am passing in data to the high-chart configuration.

```
setSeries() {
 this.objData = []
 this.Data.forEach(element => {
  var x= element['xVal'];
  var y = element['yVal'];
  var z = element['zVal'].toFixed(0);
  var name = element['seriesName'].trim();
  var newData =[{
    x:x,
    y:y,
    z:+z,
  }]
  // SetSeriesData is how i am creating the obj to pass into series=[] in highchart configuration
  if(i<50) //If I comment this condition, the graph breaks.  Right now, the graph is working properly
    this.setSeriesData(sumData, name, this.objData)
   i++
 })

 this.options.series = this.objData;
 this.generateChart();
}
```

This is my setSeriesData function.

```
setSeriesData(graphData: any, dataName: any, objData: any){
var obj = {};
obj['name'] = dataName;
obj['data'] = graphData;
obj['events'] = {click: function(e) {
  //takes me to another link
}};
objData.push(obj)
```

}

In the above function, I configured the chart so that when you click the bubble, it takes you to another page. When the data points >50, this click functionality is not working either. In addition, the fillOpacity is not correct.

Just a few things to point out 
1. I am using Angular 2+ 
2. The discovered issues are, fillOpacity, click, and size based on z-value. 
3. It works perfectly when the data points are less than 50

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Ike Jeon, do you use any additional modules, for example boost.js? Your problem can be caused by boost, which you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r0p8m6jn/

Comment: Thanks!  So when I set boost.enabled = false, the bubbles are different in sizes and colors (huge accomplishment !).  The click function is still not working.  And I can only see the bubbles when I hover my mouse over.  Other wise, it's just an empty graph.  There are quite a few modules we are using.  Could this be from other modules as well?

Comment: Your problem can be caused by many reasons. It would be best if you provide me with minimal live example with your chart options and modules.